# In Daru, how do I display multiple DataFrames in single Cell?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, sciruby, iruby, daru

In daru + iruby on jupyter, how can I display multiple tables of `Daru::DataFrame` within a single cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `IRuby.display`

For example,

[image]